# Gradle doesn't find Google Protobuf package

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers

I am trying to setup Google protobuf with netty, but when I start compilation gradle first download google protobuf (at least at the first attempt) but then at compilation it just tells me :

```
  /src/main/java/GameMoveOuterClass.java:1536: error: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 does not exist
com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.FieldAccessorTable
```

here is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
   }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.5.Final'
    compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '2.4.1'
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": 'server.Server',
        "Class-Path": configurations.compile.collect { it.getPath() }.join(' '))
    }
}
```

If someone knows what's wrong, please let me know
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You're using the version `2.4.1` of protobuf which doesn't come with `GeneratedMessageV3`.

Update to a new version of protobuf which include this class like the `3.0.0`

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.5.Final'
   compile group: 'com.google.protobuf', name: 'protobuf-java', version: '3.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [maven central advanced search](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3%22) for `com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3` it seems that the class is in `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-nio:xxx` or maybe `com.trueaccord.scalapb:protobuf-runtime-scala_yyy:zzz`. I'm guessing you'll need to add one of these to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Gradle but it looks to me like you are mixing new protobuf generated code with an older protobuf library, which is not supported. The `GeneratedMessageV3` class was added only recently (around 3.0 I believe), and so new generated code that references that class cannot be linked against an older library which does not include it.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, both my `app` and `library` module should add

```
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.9.1'
```

even `app` has a dependency on `library`